# $ω = dx_1 ∧ dy_1 + dx_2 ∧ dy_2 + dx_3 ∧ dy_3$. Prove: $∧^1 ( \mathbb{R}^6 ) \ni η \to η ∧ ω ∧ ω \in ∧^5(\mathbb{R}^6)^{*}$ is a linear isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, representation-theory, exterior-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}^6$ we take variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3$ and a bilinear form $\omega \in \wedge^2(\mathbb{R}^6)^{*}$ given by:
$$\omega = dx_1 \wedge dy_1 + dx_2 \wedge dy_2 + dx_3 \wedge dy_3$$

Prove that transformation:
$\wedge^1 ( \mathbb{R}^6 )^{*} \ni \eta \longrightarrow \eta \wedge \omega \wedge \omega \in \wedge^5(\mathbb{R}^6)^{*}$

is a linear isomorphism.

I am just starting with a book on multivariable calculus and found such a question. From linear algebra I know that to prove that a transformation is a isomorphism it's enaugh to show that it's is one to one and it's onto. How would that tanslate to that case?

Comment: In which book did you find this?

Comment: if $\eta \in \Lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^6)$, how can you wedge it with something that belongs to dual space?

Comment: @RodionZaytsev Since $\omega \in \wedge^2 (\Bbb R^6)^*$ is nondegenerate, it defines an isomorphism $\flat: \wedge^1 \Bbb R^6 \to \wedge^1 (\Bbb R^6)^*$ by $\flat(\eta)(X) = \omega(\eta, X)$.

Comment: @TravisWillse, I see, although this isomorphism was not implied by the question (and I see you've edited the body of the question anyway, though it now differs from the title).

Comment: @RodionZaytsev I did not edit the body of the question; the OP did that themselves. I only added some relevant tags. (My answer does not quite fit the new version of the question, so I suppose I'll have to update it to avoid confusion.)

Comment: @mathman12 It would be a good idea to update the title to match the body, in particular to add the dual asterisk to $\wedge^1(\Bbb R^6)$. Notice that the asterisk makes a significant difference here: To build a natural isomorphism $\wedge^1 \Bbb R^6 \to \wedge^5 (\Bbb R^6)^*$ we only need a volume form, and $\omega$ plays no real role other than to furnish one (namely, $\omega \wedge \omega \wedge \omega$). But to build a natural isomorphism $\wedge^1 (\Bbb R^6)^* \to \wedge^5 (\Bbb R^6)^*$ we need something like a bilinear form (like $\omega$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Since $\dim \wedge^1 \Bbb R^6 = {6 \choose 1} = {6 \choose 5} = \dim \wedge^5 (\Bbb R^6)^*$, (taking for granted that the map is linear---it's straightforward to verify as much) it's enough to show that the kernel of the map is trivial. To do this, a straightforward option is to compute the image under the map of a general $1$-form $\eta = \eta_1 \,dx^1 + \cdots + \eta_6 \,dy^3 \in \wedge^1 (\Bbb R^6)^*$ in terms of the coordinate cobasis.